# Que about a unique thing in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I have lots of code like below:

```
AppUtility.EnumToBool(Row["block_friends"].ToString())
```

I need to convert them to something like this.

```
AppUtility.EnumToBool(Row["block_friends"].ToString() == "1")
```

The problem is, I have around 500 instances of these and I was wondering if there would be an automated way of replacing these?

I need to do this using the Find+Replace in Visual Studio IDE, for C# code.

I now have the find part: `AppUtility\.EnumToBool\((.*)\)` but don't have the regex for the value.

Comment: Can't you just do Find & Replace `AppUtility.EnumToBool(Row["block_friends"].ToString())` with `Row["block_friends"].ToString() == "1"` or am I missing something?

Comment: `block_friends` isn't always the same, the value passed to EnumToBool isn't always the same.

Comment: Notepad++ can do this easily but it depends how your EnumToBool is passing this value ? Do you have that list ?

Comment: for regex questions it is good to provide multiple scenarios where regex passes and fails.

Comment: @PirateX it passes a string, but in programming that is impossible to list every single way a string can be passed.

Answer (score 2):

Answer working in VS2010:

### 1. Test the regex somewhere

I recommend using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for this task. Just put your sample text and get the pattern at the top and see if it's working. [This is my result](https://regex101.com/r/RYZvsD/2). You can see the regular text and changing text are caught within different groups (colors).

### 2. Rewrite the regex to match VS IDE regular expressions

There are differences. I've used `(.*)` in regex101 to group characters inside a group. In VS IDE, it must be rewritten to `{.*}`. If you want to reuse that group inside "replace with" pattern, you need to write `\1` in VS IDE (as opposed to `$1` elsewhere).

Source find pattern from regex101:
`AppUtility\.EnumToBool\(Row\[(.*)\]\.ToString\(\)\)`

VS IDE find pattern:
`AppUtility\.EnumToBool\(Row\[{.*}\]\.ToString\(\)\)`

VS IDE replace with pattern: 
`Row[\1].ToString() == "1"`

### (UPDATED) 3. Use it within IDE and see what happens

Find pattern:
`AppUtility\.EnumToBool\((.*)(\))([^\)])`

Breakdown:

1. `AppUtility\.EnumToBool\(` - takes literally AppUtility.EnumToBool
2. `(.*)` - captures the group within method, but needs 3. to work
3. `(\))([^\)])` - captures `)` char, and makes sure another character IS NOT `)` (in case of multiple `)`s

VS IDE'd:

`AppUtility\.EnumToBool\({.*}{\)}{[^\)]}`

Replace with VS IDE:

`AppUtility.EnumToBool(\1)=="1"\2\3`

Breakdown:

`AppUtility.EnumToBool(\1)=="1"` - add `=="1"` just before the last `(`
`\2\3` - add the remaining characters, so nothing is eaten

Old faulty example, just showing the replace window:

[image: Find and replace within VS IDE using regular expressions and capturing groups]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although the value passed to EnumToBool isn't always the same, it's not even close to being the same. Sometimes it's passed with a row, sometimes its passed with a method. I simply need to ignore how its passed to `EnumToBool` and just remove the method and replace with a operator.

Comment: I now have the find part: `AppUtility\.EnumToBool\((.*)\)` but don't have the regex for the value.

Comment: Can you provide sample text lines and post then on regex101 so it'll be easier to find what's needed?

Comment: For some reason isn't only detecting certain lines, but here we go. https://regex101.com/r/tvF8TN/1

Comment: If you used the `Ungreedy` flag within regex, it'd not capture multiple results within one. Actually the lines you provided have nothing in common. Posted the update for capturing `AppUtility.EnumToBool(something)`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
^AppUtility\.EnumToBool\((.*)\)$
```

with

```
\1 == "1"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it states text wasn't found, even when enabling regular expression.

Comment: I've updated my question, maybe you can check what I meant.

Comment: I now have the find part: `AppUtility\.EnumToBool\((.*)\)` but don't have the regex for the value.